# How to restrict image size to a table cell width given by text length

Tags: html, css

I have a table, with rows of a single column each, whose content (only text) define the width of the table. In one of the rows I wish to use a picture instead of text, but I want it to adapt to the cell width defined by the previous rows, so it won't force the table to resize.

Example:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Text definining the width of the table</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="some_picture.jpg"></td></tr>
</table>
```

The table is borderless, so I am open to a different solution involving other markups instead of a table (divs, for example), as long as it only uses html and css (no javascript, no fancy frameworks).

Comment: maybe try adding this style: `img { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 2):

you could get this done using **object-fit** and an **absolute position**

> The object-fit CSS property resizes the image to fit its container.

More infomations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

> The **absolute position** will effect that the image wont increase the table-cells width.
>
> Setting the table to a **relative position** will effect that the absolute positioned image will be inside its table-cell.

More informations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td class="text">Text definining the width of the table</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with both solutions is the "height: 150px". That's an arbitrary number. Ideally the image should get the proper height automatically to preserve the aspect ratio given by its new width. In the first case (background image), the larger the given height the wider the real image gets, but only shows the part that fits the width. In the second case (object-fit) also the image grows wider with a larger height, but exceeds the width of the table.

Comment: Hi @Leandro i've updated my answer. This time it could be the solution you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks again, but text rows below the image row get covered by the image :(

Comment: okay, then i think we've got to a poit where we not gonna get this done without using JS.